# Is there a sample using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 that implements integration with NemLog-in with logging and back-channel single logout?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin

I am looking into using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 for integration with NemLog-in. Is there a sample that implements the logging required by NemLog-in and supports back-channel single logout (IDP calling the SP directly to logout a user) which as far as I understand is required by NemLog-in?

I have been looking at the code for the [NemLog-in3 sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp).

My understanding is that the sample does not implement the required logging and does not support back-channel single logout. I think the /Auth/SingleLogout endpoint is only for front-channel single logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OIOSAML3 and therby NemLog-in do not support back-channel logout.

It is partly possible to use SOAP binding, which is supported by ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2. You can find some sample code in the [Artifact sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreArtifact).

Please se [OIOSAML3 chapter 4.2](https://digst.dk/media/25785/oiosaml-web-sso-profile-303.pdf).

- **Requests**
  The HTTP-Redirect binding [SAML2Bind] MUST be used for the transmission
  of (the initial) samlp:LogoutRequest messages to the IdP.
  SPs MUST support the HTTP-Redirect or HTTP-POST [SAML2Bind] binding
  for the receipt of samlp:LogoutRequest messages from the IdP, and
  MAY support SOAP binding.
- **Responses**
  The HTTP-Redirect, HTTP-POST or SOAP binding [SAML2Bind] MUST be
  used for the transmission of samlp:LogoutResponse messages to the
  IdP.
  SPs MUST support the HTTP-Redirect or HTTP-POST binding
  [SAML2Bind] binding for the receipt of samlp:LogoutResponse messages from the IdP (to the initial request).

Comment: So there are no sample with the logging required by NemLog-in and back-channel logout is not used by NemLog-in. Thanks for the quick reply.